# How to take clear screenShot IOS

Tags: ios, swift, image, screenshot

I am working on IOS Application in which taking clear screen shot is required I've tried

```
func captureView() -> UIImage {
        //hide controls if needed
        let rect: CGRect = self.imageView.frame
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.view.layer.renderInContext(context)
        let img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
```

But the quality of image is not good. Please suggest me something for it.

Comment: Have you tried with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797104/taking-screenshot-of-high-quality-ios ?

Answer (score 11):

change the line

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
```

to

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0);
```

Comment: dear do you have any idea in same code.. I am not getting proper image from imageView

Comment: great solution, the key is to set the scale to 0.0 and the screenshot will be full quality!

Answer (score 3):

Add the below code block in a new file. And, there you go.

```
extension UIView {

    // Convert a uiview to uiimage
        func captureView() -> UIImage {
            // Gradually increase the number for high resolution.     
            let scale = 1.0 

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, opaque, scale)   

            layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let image:UIImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return image
        }
    }
```

Now, you can call `captureView()` on any subclass of `UIView` and UIView itself to get the UIImage of the view.

You can change the value of `scale` in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` method to get a high resolution image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IOSurface private framework to do so

```
IOMobileFramebufferConnection connect;
kern_return_t result;
IOSurfaceRef screenSurface = NULL;

io_service_t framebufferService = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("AppleH1CLCD"));
if(!framebufferService)
    framebufferService = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("AppleM2CLCD"));
if(!framebufferService)
    framebufferService = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("AppleCLCD"));

result = IOMobileFramebufferOpen(framebufferService, mach_task_self(), 0, &connect);

result = IOMobileFramebufferGetLayerDefaultSurface(connect, 0, &screenSurface);

uint32_t aseed;
IOSurfaceLock(screenSurface, kIOSurfaceLockReadOnly, &aseed);
uint32_t width = IOSurfaceGetWidth(screenSurface);
uint32_t height = IOSurfaceGetHeight(screenSurface);

CFMutableDictionaryRef dict;
int pitch = width*4, size = width*height*4;
int bPE=4;
char pixelFormat[4] = {'A','R','G','B'};
dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceIsGlobal, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceBytesPerRow, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &pitch));
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceBytesPerElement, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &bPE));
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceWidth, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &width));
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceHeight, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &height));
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfacePixelFormat, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, pixelFormat));
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceAllocSize, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &size));

IOSurfaceRef destSurf = IOSurfaceCreate(dict);

void* outAcc;
IOSurfaceAcceleratorCreate(NULL, 0, &outAcc);

IOSurfaceAcceleratorTransferSurface(outAcc, screenSurface, destSurf, dict, NULL);

IOSurfaceUnlock(screenSurface, kIOSurfaceLockReadOnly, &aseed);
CFRelease(outAcc);

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, IOSurfaceGetBaseAddress(destSurf), (width * height * 4), NULL);
CGImageRef cgImage=CGImageCreate(width, height, 8,
                                 8*4, IOSurfaceGetBytesPerRow(destSurf),
                                 CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst |kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little,
                                 provider, NULL,
                                 YES, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(your size, opaque, scale`

instead of

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)`

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is scale. If you only need High resolution, try setting a value for scale to 1.0.

```
func captureView() -> UIImage {
        //hide controls if needed
        let rect: CGRect = self.imageView.frame

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, true, 1.0)//add this line

        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.view.layer.renderInContext(context)
        let img: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
```